# Resize THREE.ParametricGeometry to bounding box dimensions

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js

My problem is the following:

I have two intersecting surfaces created with `THREE.ParametricGeometry`. Like this:

[image: Hyperbolic paraboloid and plane in the X axis.]

I need to draw the intersection of these two surfaces. Using the Wolfram|Alpha API I get the intersection function and render it. Like this:

[image: Intersection surface.]

But, as you can see, the intersection mesh is much bigger than the two surfaces.
So I though that I could compute the intersection of the surfaces bound box (this intersection can be seen in the image above) and 'limit', so to speak, the intersection mesh to this box's dimensions.

I've tried setting the intersection mesh's scale property to the bounding box's dimensions (the difference between the box's max and min); but this only makes the intersection mesh even bigger.

Any though of how I can accomplish this?

The intersection mesh is created like this (ThreeJS r81):

```
// 'intersections' is an array of mathematical functions in string format.
intersections.forEach(function (value) {
    var rangeX = bbox.getSize().x - (bbox.getSize().x * -1);
    var rangeY = bbox.getSize().y - (bbox.getSize().y * -1);
    var zFunc = math.compile(value); // The parsing is done with MathJS
    // 'bbox' is the intersected bounding box.                

    var meshFunction = function (x, y) {
        x = rangeX * x + (bbox.getSize().x * -1);
        y = rangeY * y + (bbox.getSize().y * -1);
        var scope = {x: x, y: y};
        var z = zFunc.eval(scope);

        if (!isNaN(z))
            return new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
        else
            return new THREE.Vector3();
    };

    var geometry = new THREE.ParametricGeometry(meshFunction, segments, segments,
        true);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: defaults.intersectionColor,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    intersectionMeshes.push(mesh);
    // 'intersectionMeshes' is returned and then added to the scene.
});
```

Comment: So if I'm not mistaken, the intersection is correct but you just want to clip it?

Comment: Yes, I just want to clip it to the bounding box.

Comment: Sorry, I never used the WolframAlpha API, but did you try to change the default intersection bounds with some API parameters based on the bounds of your surfaces?
That would be very convenient.

Comment: Mmmm... Not, I did not. I do not think I'll work, but it does not hurt to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that scaling the intersection mesh wouldn't work as the intersection would become incorrect.

Let's try to do this with [*Three.js clipping*](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_clipping.html) :

1. Set `renderer.localClippingEnabled` to `true` ;
2. Compute the bounding box of the surfaces ;
3. For every 6 sides of the bounding box, compute a plane with the normal pointing **inside** the box.
   (e.g. right-side : `new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(-1,0,0), -bbox.max.x);`)
   You now have an array of clipping planes ;
4. Create a new `THREE.Material` with `material.clippingPlanes` being the array of clipping planes ;
5. Use this material for the intersection mesh.

Note that with local clipping, the intersection mesh and the surface meshes should share the same world transformation. (putting all these meshes into a `THREE.Group` would be reasonable.)

Comment: Excellent, thank you for your answer. I'll try this and get back to you.

Comment: So I was trying this, and I realized I don't quite understand your third point. If it's a `THREE.Plane` for every 6 sides that means I will end up with two planes, right? And in which direction should the normal vector be?

Comment: No I mean the 6 planes of your bounding box (the one that contains the 2 surfaces). You should end up with 6 planes, each plane has its normal pointing towards the mesh. I edited the answer, tell me if it's not clear.

Comment: OK, now I get it. I'll try that, tanks for the clarification.